# Ruby: How can I insert a single value between each item in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array `[1,2,3]` and I want to insert the same value (`true`) between each item so that it becomes:

```rb
#=> [1, true, 2, true, 3, true]
```

My current method is a little long-winded:

```rb
[1,2,3].zip(Array.new(3, true)).flatten
```

Can anyone suggest a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What are going to do with this array after? Maybe there's an easier way to do _that_ than going through a temp array.

Comment: Your text and your example do not match up. In your text, you say you want to insert a single value *between* items, whereas in your code example, you are adding a value *after* each item. Also, your question is confusing since you are asking about inserting a value *between each item*, which doesn't make sense, since you cannot insert something between one thing, you can only insert it between two things.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `flat_map`, and add after each element a `true` object:

```
p [1, 2, 3].flat_map { |e| [e, true] } # [1, true, 2, true, 3, true]
```

Another way would be to get the product of `[1,2,3]` and `[true]`, and flatten the result:

```
p [1, 2, 3].product([true]).flatten # [1, true, 2, true, 3, true]
```

Answer (score 2):

Only a small tweak: Your code suffers from having to know the number of elements in the array being processed. This takes the form of the magic number 3 used to make the true array. Here is an alternative. Better? Dunno, but at least no magic numbers to break.

```
[1,2,3].zip([true].cycle).flatten
```

yields

```
[1, true, 2, true, 3, true]
```

Curious note: Adding a space between the "zip" and the opening "(" will cause the interpreter (version 2.3.3 in my tests) to generate an error:

```
Error NoMethodError: undefined method `flatten' for #<Enumerator: [true]:cycle>
```

This may be more robust as it avoids ambiguity in Ruby's "friendly" parser:

```
([1,2,3].zip([true].cycle)).flatten
```